# How can we set custom image as background for desktop and login screen

Tags: 14.04, login, login-screen, desktop-background

If we select default wallpapers in Ubuntu as desktop background image it will automatically set the same image as login screen. But if we use a custom image as a wallpaper it will only change the desktop background but the login screnn will change to a default wallpaper. Why this is happening and how can we set a custom image as background for both desktop and login screen

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A simple **trick** copy that pic to the background folder

```
sudo cp somepic.jpg /usr/share/backgrounds/
```

#### Now the perfect solution:

1. Make sure your wallpaper is readable by lightdm

   ```
   chmod 644 somepic.jpg
   ```
2. Run this command:

   ```
   gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds true.
   ```

   This to enable unity-greeter background drawing if it's not
3. Run this command:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true
   ```

Comment: copied my picture file to `/usr/share/backgrounds/` , changed file permission and run gsettings command but still not working

Comment: Install ubuntu tweak and try from there. you can there indicate which to background and which to put as login wallpaper